# Varnish basic config file throws "VCL compilation failed" when I try to use std.syslog. Why?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have a simple VCL file as follows:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "3333";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    std.log("req.host: "+req.host);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

}

sub vcl_deliver {

}
```

When I try to start `varnishd` with this config on my Mac, I get the following error:

```
Error:
Message from VCC-compiler:
Symbol not found: 'req.host' (expected type STRING):
('/Users/jononomo/dev/my_project/deploy/testing.vcl' Line 30 Pos 26)
    std.log("req.host: "+req.host);
-------------------------########--

('/Users/jononomo/dev/my_project/deploy/testing.vcl' Line 30 Pos 5) -- ('/Users/jononomo/dev/my_project/deploy/testing.vcl' Line 30 Pos 25)
    std.log("req.host: "+req.host);
----#####################----------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
VCL compilation failed
```

I have tried different variations of this line:

```
std.log("req.host: "+req.host);
```

such as:

```
std.log(req.host: '+req.host);
std.log("req.host: ",req.host);
std.log('req.host: ',req.host);
std.log('hello');
```

but none of them work.

How can I do simple logging from my VCL file?

Thanks.

UPDATE:  `std.log("hello")` seems to compile... however, I need to log information about the request object and `req`, `request`, etc do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `req.http.host` instead:

```cpp
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "3333";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    std.log("req.host: " + req.http.host);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

}

sub vcl_deliver {

}
```

Comment: Thanks - and correct!  But how can I examine the `req` object more generally?

Comment: There is no way to dump ```req``` object with all of its contents, but documentation [here](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vcl.html#req) contains some insight on available variables. So basically ```req.http.arbitary-header-name``` allows you to inspect any HTTP header provided by client in request.